# MySQL Update WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a feeling that my syntax is incorrect but I can't narrow down what's going on.  I have no issues running the statement in a phpMyAdmin SQL query, so hopefully I can get pointed in the right direction.  My code is as follows:

```
else if ($resultdetails === 1) {
    $query3 = "update customer_det set `10k`='$_10k', 
      `14k`='$_14k', `18k`='$_18k', `21k`='$_21k', `22k`='$_22k', 
      `24k`='$_24k', `925k`='$_925k', `coins`='$coins', `bars`='$bars' 
      where `id` = '".$uid."'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
}
```

`$resultdetails` is a variable set with a EXISTS function.  In the SQL query, it returns `1` for me, because the row I'm looking for does exist. So there should be no issues with that.

I tried the double `==`, as well as the triple, and there doesn't seem to be any difference in results.  I believe the triple `===` means that it's identical, i.e. the datatype is the same and the value is the same.

I think the issue here is the WHERE statement. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I forgot to mention that `customer_det` is the table to be updated and `id` is the primary key, autoincremented. I pull the `$uid` variable from the database as well.

Comment: have you tried running the query in phpmyadmin directly against your database (or atleast a test one!) it will give you a greater idea of any syntax errors etc.

Comment: The query runs fine in the phpMyAdmin SQL query box.  That's why I'm unsure as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the datatype for $uid ?? if its int remove the '' from your query.

Comment: so if you output $query3 so youi can see what's gone in it. Does it make sense. Can't see syntax error, $uid not being waht you think it is, more likely

Comment: Hm, I believe that it is an integer.  I can see the issue would be "" is trying to datatype as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql query is right !
But your `else if` is the problem !
see you add `===`,
change it with `==` and i'm also doubt with your variable declare,
your code will look
like this:

```
else if ($resultdetails == 1) {
$query3 = "update customer_det set `10k`='".$_10k."',
`14k`='".$_14k."', `18k`='".$_18k."',
`21k`='".$_21k."', `22k`='".$_22k."', `24k`='".$_24k."', `925k`='".$_925k."', `coins`='".$coins."', `bars`='".$bars."' where `id` = '".$uid."'";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
 if (CONDITION :: IF FOUND ON DATABASE) {
  $query3 = "update customer_det set `10k`='".$_10k."',
 `14k`='".$_14k."', `18k`='".$_18k."',
 `21k`='".$_21k."', `22k`='".$_22k."', `24k`='".$_24k."', `925k`='".$_925k."',        `coins`='".$coins."', `bars`='".$bars."' where `id` = '".$uid."'";
 $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
 } else {
 // Insert query if not found
 }
```

Comment: You're right, now I'm getting a blank insert because I changed the first IF to double ==.  The first IF statement says if record doesn't exist then insert, the else if is the statement provided, if exists, update.

Comment: Ok i will be help you ...
I will edit my question ...
The important you must know and get learn more !
Wait me ...

Comment: I has edit my answer, please learn my way !
I want you to know how to PHP and MySQL showng the power !

Comment: I echo'd the $resultdetails and it's saying Resource ID #11.  So that means I need to return a value and not an object correct?

Comment: can you create one more question with full of your code ?
I will first to answer it, because i did'nt get catch if you only say ! Please sir !, Spirit !

Answer (score 0):

Check for the data type for `$uid` and `$_blahblah`

Try this query --

```
else if ($resultdetails == 1) {
    $query3 = "update customer_det set `10k`='$_10k', 
      `14k`='$_14k', `18k`='$_18k', `21k`='$_21k', `22k`='$_22k', 
      `24k`='$_24k', `925k`='$_925k', `coins`='$coins', `bars`='$bars' 
      where `id` = $uid";
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
}
```

Comment: I removed the ' as well as the " and tried it each time, still failing to get an update.  I echo UID before the request and UID returns 273.  So basically it's trying to update the record where id = 273.

Comment: echo $query3; and then run the query in mysql and check if its running or not?

Comment: Ya $query3 won't even echo, so it looks like it's not being executed.

Comment: @user1718270 check it with a die; that is it really going inside it or not and then tell me

Comment: @user1718270 try this -> else if ($resultdetails == 1) { echo "Hello"; die; and check if its showing hello or not??

Comment: I echo'd two different statements, it looks like neither is executing on the IF / ELSE IF