# MySQL EXISTS return 1 or 0

Tags: php, mysql, select

How can I return the 1 or 0 as true and false for my select query?  I've tried every combination of fetch_assoc, arrays, etc.  It usually returns as null, which doesn't make sense.

```
$querydetails = "select exists (select * from customer_det where id = $uid)";
$resultdetails = mysql_query($querydetails) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultdetails)) {
    $resultdetails1 = $row[0];
}
```

That's the latest version of my query.  I guess it's not an array, but I'm not sure how to pull the value if there's no row to be named?

This is a post question to my previous thread: [MySQL Update WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177364/mysql-update-where)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The quick way to check if SELECT EXISTS(...) returns a value, using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484974/the-quick-way-to-check-if-select-exists-returns-a-value-using-php)

Comment: You should switch to mysqli, mysql is deprecated. That means there is no support for it from now on, a better version exists, and people here will get mad if you post a question that is using it.

Comment: I apologize is this is a duplicated question, I did not see that question posted.  Nonetheless, I can return a 1 or a 0 while inserting that into the SQL query of phpMyAdmin, but I can't get it to return with the PHP

Comment: @asad The php version running on the server does not support mysqli.  I realize this is an issue, but hopefully someone will be updating it in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(...),1,0) AS result
```

Answer (score 3):

simple use `COUNT` and `IF`

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = 0, 0, 1)
FROM table1
WHERE s = 2
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a122/5)

Comment: EXISTS can do this without count. Simply use a LIMIT 1 clause inside a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1
) AS result;
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using mysql version 8.0.23 on AMS

```
SELECT
column1,
column2,
IF (exists(select * from MeasurementItemNos measureItem where measureItem.itemNo = ib.itemNo and measureItem.IsActive = 1),1,0) as isUploadedSizeSpec
from table
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do:

```
select * from customer_det where id = $uid LIMIT 1
```

You will get either 1 row or zero rows.

Comment: You will more likely get one actual row of data, or the empty set.