# MySQL SELECT EXISTS on Multiple Values

Tags: mysql

I believe this should be relatively simple but I can't seem to figure out the logic to it.

I'll start with what I'm looking for. I wanted to be able to pass in values (such as e-mail addresses) through a SELECT query and have it output whether those rows exist or not. It would be something like this:

```
# PASS Values test@test.com and example@example.com in.
# For these purposes let's pretend that test@test.com exists
# and example@example.com does not.

+----------------------+--------+
| E-mail               | Exists |
+----------------------+--------+
| test@test.com        | 1      |
| example@example.com  | 0      |
+----------------------+--------+
```

There is the answer here for a single result: [MySQL EXISTS return 1 or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178261/mysql-exists-return-1-or-0) but I would like to expand on that and am having issues figuring it out.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you can't do this with `in` alone.  One option is to create a subquery with an `outer join`, and then use  `case`:

```
select t.email, 
       case when yt.email is not null then 1 else 0 end `exists`
from (select 'test@test.com' as email union all select 'example@example.com') t
    left join yourtable yt on t.email = yt.email
```

Note: backticks are needed on `exists` in the statement.

Comment: This makes sense. It is throwing an error that I'm trying to identify. The error is: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'exists,from (select 'test@test.com' as email union all select 'example@example. at line 2 `. Another question, I would be able to put as many e-mails as I'd like onto that union all select statement, correct?

Comment: I tried removing the `union all select` statement to just test the one e-mail address but that also threw an error. It seems to be a syntax error...

Comment: @MillerMedia Remove the comma after 'exists' word

Comment: I removed the commas and still nothing. The error message is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcbpzsnv6ic5ga3/Screenshot%202016-07-05%2015.02.16.png?dl=0 . It still seems to be indicating a syntax error. It's erroring around 'test@test.' ...could the period be causing some issue?

Comment: @MillerMedia -- look at your `select` statement.  You should have a comma after `t.email`, but not after `exists`: `select field1, field2 from...`.  Also be aware that `exists` is a keyword and may need to be escaped with backticks.

Comment: Yes, I did leave the comma after t.email and it still gave the same error. Let me try to backtick `exists` and I'll let you know what I get.

Comment: That was it. exists needs backticks on it. Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: Question (and apologies; I'm trying to wrap my mind around the concept), I'm looking to expand the query to scale to have more than just two inputs. I know I can't just add an extra e-mail to the union all select statement because then it wouldn't have as many fields as the select statement itself. But if I just add an arbitrary field to the select statement then the join doesn't pick all of the arguments up. I'm probably overthinking it, but is there a quick way to just scale the query to be able to scale the query to check more e-mails?